# Differences between PNP and NPN BJT?

Tags: transistors

Are there any differences between properties of PNP and NPN BJT's  such as doping levels, noise levels ,differences in manufacturing methods etc.

Comment: This question needs more focus, or more prior research so that a more focused, specific question can be asked.

Answer (score 2):

If you understand an NPN transistor, then a PNP is very straightforward. Just swap the N and P regions, and change the bias polarities.

Both types can be used, depending on how you connect them, for amplifying voltage, current, or both at the same time.

With the silicon we presently use to make semiconductors, NPN devices work 'better' than PNPs, so they are the type that dominate, because, physics. However, many circuits need a transistor 'the other way up', so some PNPs are made for that purpose. In the old germanium days, it was the other way round, PNPs abounded and there were few NPNs made.

Comment: For what exact reasons I forget, NPN/PNP performance is more modest, like 10% -- the mobility is a factor, but a relatively minor one when minority carriers (of both types) are involved, as is the case for BJTs.  It is FETs which suffer the ~2.5x mobility penalty.  Germanium I believe was a matter of fabrication, with P-doping coming for free with "alloy" contacts; NPNs I think perform better there as well, they just weren't feasible (and by the time they were (the application of stereolithography), Si was even better still).

Comment: @TimWilliams I remember reading the same thing about BJTs.. I, too, would love a rigorous explanation why mobility is supposedly not an issue.